# div size relative to screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm programming a html5 app with JQuery Mobile and Phonegap. I want to run them on many different devices. Because of that, I want to have everything relative to screen size.

```
<div id="pos" data-role="content"
        style="border: 5px solid silver; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 250px; height: 250px;">
```

I use this div Element to display a google map inside with a little border around.

How can I adjust the size for example 80% of the screen size?

I tried it with width: 90%; height: 90%, but the result is really bad. Its not relative to screen, it lokks like relative to the content.

And the size of the border is fixed with 5px, is it possible to insert here a nice argument to have it relative to screen size?

I hope someone can help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A html element, set to `width: 100%`, stretches to a `100%` of it's parents width. You need to make sure that the containing elements widths are also `100%`.

You also need to make the `html` and `body` width `100%`.

An example:

```
html, body { width: 100%; }
#pos { width: 80%; }
```

This example assumes the #pos element is straight on the body.

Comment: And how exactly does this differ, when speaking mobile? Are you gonna resize your browser on your mobile device?

Comment: Why isn't this working? It shows a div with 100% width and the height as the text has<style>html, body, geolocation { width: 100%; height: 100%; } 
#pos { width: 80%; height: 80%; } 

</style>
</head>

<body>
 <div data-role="page" id="geolocation" data-theme="a">
  <h2 align="center">Geolocation</h2>
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
   <h1>Car Data</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="pos" data-role="content" style="border: 5px solid silver;">
   Your position will be calculated...</div>

Comment: It works fine running in Chrome, with only the html you provided.
Which browser are you testing with?

Comment: Android WebView on Android 4.1.1, could that cause the problem?

Comment: Try with this entire code: -- 

<html><style>html, body, geolocation { width: 100%; height: 100%; } #pos { width: 80%; height: 80%; } </style> </head> <body> <div data-role="page" id="geolocation" data-theme="a"> <h2 align="center">Geolocation</h2> <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a"> <h1>Car Data</h1> </div> <div id="pos" data-role="content" style="border: 5px solid silver;"> Your position will be calculated...</div></div></body></html>

Comment: I postet my whole code as an answer, because of the overview and characters left.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14170/discussion-between-kao-and-fluxim)

Answer (score 0):

you might need to define the height and width of the parents if you dont want to use js
here i made an example on jsfiddle
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44QS3/)

Answer (score 0):

looks good, so I think the problem is because of JQuery! Here is my complete code of this page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> App</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>

<style>

  html, body, geolocation { width: 100%; height: 100%; } 
  #pos { width: 80%; height: 80%; } 

</style>
</head>

 <body>
<div data-role="page" id="geolocation" data-theme="a">
    <h2 align="center">Geolocation</h2>
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
        <h1>Car Data</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="pos" data-role="content" style="border: 5px solid silver;">
        Deine Position wird ermittelt...</div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="geolocation.js"></script>


    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="persFooter">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="home.html" data-icon="home">Connect</a></li>
                <li><a href="carView.html" data-icon="gear">Vehicles</a></li>
                <li><a href="infoView.html" data-icon="info">Info</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


<script>                                       
    $('#geolocation').on('swipeleft',function(){ 
     $.mobile.changePage("fuelGauge.html", { transition: "slide"}); 
     console.log('slideLeft');
    })  

    $('#geolocation').on('swiperight',function(){ 
     $.mobile.changePage("batteryStatus.html", { transition: "slide", reverse: 'true'});    
     console.log('slideLeft');
    })                                       
</script>
</div>



  </body>
  </html>
```